# how to decide which class tag i should use to crawl data from website using scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am new to python and scrapy and i want crawl bank names from website. I am using scrapy but I am confuse about what class name to use in response.css('_______::text').extract()[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQigK.png)to get the name of bank.
I have included screenshot of inspect of page.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQigK.png)

Answer (score 1):

As you can see there's no class in `a` element. So you can use parent in [xpath](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html) selector.

```
response.xpath('.//table[@class="tablebg"]//td[2]/a/text()')
```

This selector can contain some typo, but it would be better next time if you'll provide site link.